# build oracle sql query dynamically from java application

Tags: java, sql, oracle, dynamic

How do I build oracle pl/sql query dynamically from a java application? The user will be presented with a bunch of columns that are present in different tables in the database. The user can select any set of column and the application should build the complete select query using only the tables that contain the selected columns.
For example, lets consider that there are 3 tables in the database. The user selects col11, col22. In this case, the application should build the query using Tabl1 and Tabl2 only.
How do I achieve this?

```
Tabl1
 - col11
 - col12
 - col13

Tabl2
 - fkTbl1
 - col21
 - col22
 - col23

Tabl3
 - col31
 - col32
 - col33
 - fkTbl1
```

Comment: The problem with giving users this extreme level of flexibility is that it'd be too easy for them to get into trouble with very poorly performing SQL. I'd recommend using some kind of software designed for this purpose, unless your users are SQL-savvy enough to write their own queries.

Answer (score 5):

Ad hoc reporting is an old favourite.  It frequently appears as a one-liner at the end of the Reports Requirements section: "Users must be able to define and run their own reports".  The only snag is that ad hoc reporting is *an application in its own right*.

You say

> "The user will be presented with a
>   bunch of columns that are present in
>   different tables in the database."

You can avoid some of the complexities I discuss below if the "bunch of columns" (and the spread of tables) is preselected and tightly controlled.  Alas, it is in the nature of ad hoc reporting that users will want pretty much all columns from all tables.

Let's start with your example.  The user has selected `col11` and `col22`, so you need to generate this query:

```
SELECT tabl1.col11
       , tabl2.col22
FROM tabl1 JOIN tabl2 
     ON  (TABL1.ID = TABL2.FKTABL1)
/
```

That's not too difficult.  You just need to navigate the data dictionary views `USER_CONSTRAINTS` and `USER_CONS_COLUMNS` to establish the columns in the join condition - providing you have defined foreign keys (please have foreign keys!).

Things become more complicated if we add a fourth table:

```
Tabl4
 - col41
 - col42
 - col43
 - fkTbl2
```

Now when the user choose `col11` and `col42` you need to navigate the data dictionary to establish that `Tabl2` acts as an intermediary table to join `Tabl4` and `Tabl1` (presuming you are not using composite primary keys, as most people don't).  But suppose the user selects `col31` and `col41`.  Is that a legitimate combination?  Let's say it is.  Now you have to join `Tabl4` to `Tabl2` to `Tabl1` to `Tabl3`.  Hmmm...

And what if the user selects columns from two completely unrelated tables - `Tabl1` and `Tabl23`?  Do you blindly generate a `CROSS JOIN` or do you hurl an exception?  The choice is yours.

Going back to that first query, it will return all the rows in both tables.  Almost certainly your users will want the option to restrict the result set.  So you need to offer them the ability to add to filters to the `WHERE` clause.  Gotchas here include:

- ensuring that supplied values are of an appropriate data-type (no strings for a number, no numbers for a date)
- providing look-ups to reference data
  values
- handling multiple values (`IN` list
  rather than equals)
- ensuring date ranges are sensible
  (opening bound before closing bound)
- handling free text searches (are you
  going to allow it?  do you need to
  use TEXT indexes or will you run the
  risk of users executing `LIKE`
  `'%whatever%'` against some CLOB
  column?)

The last point highlights one risk inherent in ad hoc reporting: if the users can assemble a query from any tables with any filters they can assemble a query which can drain all the resources from your system.  So it is a good idea to apply [profiles](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/concepts/profile.html) to prevent that happening.  Also, as I have already mentioned, it is possible for the users to build  nonsensical queries.  Bear in mind that you don't need very many tables in your schema to generate too many permutations to test.

Finally there is the tricky proposition of security policies.  If users are restricted to seeing subsets of data on the basis their department or their job role, then you will need to replicate those rules.  In such cases the automatic application of policies through [Row Level Security](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_rls.htm) is a real boon

All of which might lead you to conclude that the best solution would be to pursuade your users to acquire an off-the-shelf product instead.  Although that approach isn't without its own problems.

Answer (score 0):

The way that I've done this kind of thing in the past is to simply construct the SQL query on the fly using a StringBuilder and then executing it using a JDBC a non-prepared statement.  This is rather inefficient since the Oracle DB has to repeat all of the query analysis and optimization work for each query.

Comment: Not to mention the security considerations!

Comment: @atc - it depends on what you are building the query from.  But yes, that is certainly a concern.